# Wi-Fi won't connect to my computer

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, internet

I am new to programming with Linux, so sorry if my words are not correct. I will try to be precise and give useful info.

My computer runing Ubuntu 19.04 isn't connecting to Wi-Fi, and when I check my phones' connection ability, it works fine.

I tried to solve my problem using this tuto : 
https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wi-fi-not-working-ubuntu/

If I understand correctly, it is either a hardware or software problem. So, I checked if my computer registeres the internet chip, but I can't tell.

When I run this command sudo lsusb I get this : [result of lsusb command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju140.png)

I can't find in this result “Network Controller” or “Ethernet Controller.” does it mean my computer doesn't find the chip?

When I run this command lshw -C network, I get this output : [output lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRM5G.png)

This makes me think that my computer does have an internet chip?

I am confused on whether I have a hardware issue.

I hope it is clear, and that you will be able to help me understand what I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer does recognise your Wifi chip. In the `lsusb` command you have a device called "Qualcomm Atheros Communications". That is your wireless chip. "Network Controller"and "Ethernet Controller" are commonly in the name of networking chips, however it is slightly misleading, in that they will be more commonly used for Ethernet (ie wired) network chips.

You should continue with step two of the guide.

Side note: You are not particularly clear with your phone - how are you tethering it? It doesn't really matter over here - I assume you are using Bluetooth or USB. Just a wording help for the future.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. In the tutorial they refer to the name of the chip that I need to use in another command, but I can't find it. When I do command `lsmod` i can't see what is related to the name of the chip?  I also tried command `lshw -C network` and tried doing command `sudo modprobe modulename` with info from `lshw -C network`. How do I find the name of the chip?

Comment: @user1106292 The name of the chip in your case is Qualcomm Atheros Communications.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu may not have drivers for newer WiFi adapters. You can [download the drivers for your particular adapter and build them on your PC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326462/how-do-i-install-atheros-ar9271-wifi-drivers-on-debian).

First check online or in your user manual for the mode number of the WiFi adapter rather than downloading *all* drivers.

For more information, search the web using `[your computer model] Ubuntu Atheros WiFi driver`.

Comment: I tried downloading the corresponding driver and it worked for a bit. The problem arises when I try to use a network repeater, it confuses my computer to find networks.